# I have a question about Subscription Duplicate purchase Issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am implementing a subscription feature using *Unity IAP*.

I am currently testing purchases with Sandbox account through *Testflight*.

I initially completed my subscription. If I try to subscribe again immediately, "You are currently subscribed" message window appears. And the window has two buttons "Manage" and "OK".

If I click "OK" button, the subscription is purchased again.

I think that if I already have a subscription, payment should fail.

And if I click "Manage" button, I can't find my subscription info.

I can't find solution and I don't know reason.

If I test using the *testflight* environment and the sandbox account, can the results differ from the actual ones?

I hope to get a clue on this issue.

Comment: What is your device?

Comment: my device is iphone. and testing with sandbox account through Testflight.